# Cannot launch AVD in emulator.Android studio 2.1.2

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-studio-2.1

OUTPUT-

```
    Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
    Output:
    emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
    emulator: ERROR: Could not create C:\Users\Mahe\.android\avd\Nexus_S_API_22_2.avd/userdata-qemu.img: No such file or directory
```

I am a beginner in android and this error popped up when I first started the emulator.

Comment: I suggest that you install the newest version of Android Studio and try again.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am doing a course and it is mentioned to use this version